Intel Wifi 7 BE201 in Ubuntu 22.04
I recently just bought a Dell XPS 13 with Intel Wifi 7 BE201. I tried the live USB for Ubuntu 22.04. Ethernet works fine, but it seems like I can't connect to any wifi at all. It said it couldn't find any drivers for wifi.
Is it because BE201 isn't supported yet atm?

Sadly, this seems to be the case. After checking the table at https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html, be201 is not supported.
Edit: I found a thread here at intel community page, please leave a comment if you are also looking for be201 driver.
